# Add text box in a new row and in two different columns

Tags: php, javascript

I have found a script to add text box to the window using button. But problem is the logic used to add text boxes is using `div`. Using div tag increases the page length as it uses a lot of blank space. Please help me with the script such that I can add text boxes in the tabular form that is in the `tr` & `td` tags.

PHP page script.

```
<td COLSPAN="3"><DIV id='TextBoxesGroup'><DIV id="TextBoxDiv1"><LABEL>Track #1 : </LABEL>
<input name="textbox1[]" type='text' size="60" id='textbox11' >
<input name="textbox2[]" type='text' size="35" id='textbox21' >
</DIV></DIV></td>
```

Javascript..

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {
if(counter>25){
alert("Only 25 textboxes allow");
return false;
}   
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
.attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Track #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
'<input name="textbox1[]" size="60" type="text" id="textbox1' + counter + '">' + '&nbsp;'+  '<input name="textbox2[]" size="35" type="text" id="textbox2' + counter + '">' );

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


counter++;
});

$("#removeButton").click(function () {
if(counter==1){
alert("No more textbox to remove");
return false;
}   

counter--;

$("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

});

$("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

var msg = '';
for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
}
alert(msg);
});
});
```

Comment: Please spend smoe time making your code more readable...the indentation and line skipping here is all over the road.

Comment: "Using div tag increases the page length as it uses a lot of blank space"... what?

Comment: Simply I want to use td tag instead of div.

Comment: Yes, please do make it easier to read.  If you are using dreamweaver, try to autoformat or something.  Even getting rid of all of the indentation might help.  Also, if you still can, add the jquery tag.

Comment: Can you improve your question title, please? "Help with script" is completely useless, and borderline redundant on SO anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just remove the part of the code that creates the divs.

```
newdiv = $('<label>Track #'+ counter + ' : </label>' + '<input name="textbox1[]" size="60" type="text" id="textbox1' + counter + '">' + '&nbsp;'+  '<input name="textbox2[]" size="35" type="text" id="textbox2' + counter + '">' );
newdiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
```

However, if any of your code depends on the div being present elsewhere, this will not work.

Comment: It gives no effect to the page. Actually I want to add text box each time in a new row and in two different columns.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like this is really more of an HTML question and when you add a div, you aren't getting the formatting you want.  A DIV is (by default) a block object which starts a new line.  I can't really tell what exactly you want the result to be, but if you want an inline object, you can use a SPAN instead.  You would change this line:

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
```

to this:

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('span'))
```

Also, if you want the new checkbox to be added to the same container that has your current checkboxes in it, then you may want to change this:

```
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
```

to this:

```
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxDiv1");
```

Further help will lkely require more of an explanation of the finished formatting you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can't you modify script to put each time in new td data. with new tr tag... I don't want to span or div tag to my page. So please help.

Comment: Yes, you could put in a new row in the table.  If that's what you wanted, then you could have asked for that.  Is that what your question is here: "How to change the output of this function to put the results into a new row <tr> in your table"?  If so, you will have to share more of the HTML than you have because we can't see the part of the table at the row level to know how to create a new row.  FYI, a <span> tag won't change your formatting at all - it just provides formatting flexibility if you want to style things.  A <div> does cause a new line.